# No such option error in python-zipline

Tags: python, quantitative-finance, zipline

I am a newbie to zipline. I am following the beginner tutorial to get familiar with it. And when I tried to run the algorithm as taught by tutorial in the ipython cell:

```
from zipline.api import order_target, record, symbol, history
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from zipline.examples import buyapple
%load_ext zipline
%%zipline --start 2000-1-1 --end 2014-1-1 --symbols AAPL


def initialize(context):
    pass

def handle_data(context, data):
    order(symbol('AAPL'), 10)
    record(AAPL=data[symbol('AAPL')].price)
```

I got such an error: `NoSuchOption: no such option: --symbols`

I tried to run `python -m zipline run -f ../../zipline/examples/buyapple.py --start 2000-1-1 --end 2014-1-1 --symbols AAPL -o buyapple_out.pickle` in the cli and also got the same error. Do you know what's the reason and how can I fix it? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @Shakti I think the reason is the document isn't up-to-date. Check [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/zipline/MUO7jdzUOss) out.

Comment: Thanks it worked .

Answer (score 1):

I ran this command `$ zipline ingest` which defaulted to fetching quantopian-quandl data bundle.

After that finished downloading I removed the offending switch: `--symbols AAPL` and the tutorial seemed to run correctly.